# How can I add select2 dynamic select box inside a while loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, while-loop, jquery-select2

I'm trying to put a Select2 box inside a while loop. But it only works the first select tag. Although loop works fine, the select tag is not working after the first 1. how can I fix this issue?

I also tried adding printing PHP unique id to fix it. but nothing happened.

```
<select type="text" name="city" id="city-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="form-control"></select>
```

This is the javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#city-<?php echo $id; ?>').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select city',
    ajax: {
        url: 'processes/cities.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm expecting all the select boxes to work fine. But actually, only first 1 works.

Comment: Make sure that the id on both select (select2) are unique.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provided the loop in your code example.
The most likely problem is that your id's are not unique. If you have multiple tags with the same id then javascript will only recognize the first one.
Here's an example to demonstrate.

https://jsfiddle.net/n8vxjoc1/1/

```
<div id="city-1">Content</div>
<div id="city-1">Content</div>
<script>
  jQuery( '#city-1' ).html( jQuery( '#city-1' ).length );
</script>
```

Only the 1st element will change and it will display the number 1.

From the W3C specs:

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

You should give the select dropdowns a class and target that instead.
E.g.

https://jsfiddle.net/n8vxjoc1/1/

```
<select name="city" class="select2 form-control">…</select>
<select name="city" class="select2 form-control">…</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select.select2').select2({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from this link: [Demo](https://makitweb.com/how-to-add-select2-on-dynamic-element-jquery/)

```
    <select class="select2_el" style='width: 200px;'>
   <option value='0'>- Search user -</option>
</select>

<div id='elements'>

</div>
<input type="button" id="btn_add" value="Add">
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';// add your config details on that file

$request = 1;
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
  $request = $_POST['request'];
}

// Select2 data
if($request == 1){
  if(!isset($_POST['searchTerm'])){
     $fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users order by name limit 5");
  }else{
     $search = $_POST['searchTerm'];
     $fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where name like '%".$search."%' limit 5");
  }

  $data = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchData)) {
     $data[] = array("id"=>$row['id'], "text"=>$row['name']); 
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
  exit;
}

// Add element
if($request == 2){

   $html = "<br><select class='select2_el' ><option value='0'>- Search user -</option></select><br>";
   echo $html;
   exit;

}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Initialize select2
  initailizeSelect2();

  // Add <select > element
  $('#btn_add').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {request: 2},
       success: function(response){

         // Append element
         $('#elements').append(response);

         // Initialize select2
         initailizeSelect2();
       }
     });
  });

});

// Initialize select2
function initailizeSelect2(){

   $(".select2_el").select2({
     ajax: {
       url: "ajaxfile.php",
       type: "post",
       dataType: 'json',
       delay: 250,
       data: function (params) {
          return {
            searchTerm: params.term // search term
          };
       },
       processResults: function (response) {
          return {
             results: response
          };
       },
       cache: true
     }
   });
}
```